# How can we copy code blocks from Stack Overflow to the clipboard?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there functionality on Stack Overflow to copy code blocks from questions to the clipboard?

For long code fragments, it is quite inconvenient to scroll and select.

It would be nice to have a "Copy" button without any extra extensions which are always a security risk.

I see the related [Shortcut or button for copying posted code from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow), but it is 13 years old and I can't get if it was solved somehow or what the plans are for it.

Comment: There is at least one from this year.

Comment: Or was it/they (automatically) deleted? The [linked questions'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/251883?sort=newest) newest is from 2021.

Comment: IMO: making it too easy too copy and paste is the biggest security risk of them all. That moment of slog is a moment where you are forced to think about what you're doing. We can't have enough of those. Copying code from Stack Overflow should be done with extreme prejudice.

Comment: @Gimby, makes sense, thank you. The only question, what is the difference from security perspective between copying with button and copying just from selecting on screen, or even worse from security perspective, by third-party plugin or with just selecting and copying, or with opening html source and copying, etc.?